# Clarification on the idea of Mathematical Statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

The two statements below were left as an exercise to the viewers on this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPN6IJ7isEE&t=26s) about Mathematical statements.

1. Sum of 2 integers is positive.
2. Sum of 2 integers can never be negative.

Most of the answers in the comments say that both statements are mathematical statements. After giving enough thought on these statements, I believe that the first one is NOT a mathematical statement because it is ambiguous while the second one is indeed a mathematical statement.

I believe that it is valid to interpret the second statement as equivalent to `The sum of any pair of integers can never be negative` because of the presence of the word '`never`'. However, I think the same is not true for the first one. I don't know how to explain it but I think `Sum of 2 integers is positive` cannot be interpreted as `The sum of any pair of integers is positive.`

Comment: So what is the question here exactly? One could also argue there's an implicit "every" in the first point of interest. Persistent warning: careful when mixing language with mathematical logic. There's not always a smooth carryover.

Comment: First of all, we have the ambiguity about [Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer): if we stay with integer=not a fraction, the two are simply false. Having said that, without context the issue about the reading of "The sum of 2 integers is positive" and that of "The sum of 2 integers can never be negative" is not with "can" and "never". We may rewrite the second one without them and it becomes: "The sum of 2 integers cannot be negative", that has the same grammatical form of the fist one.

Comment: In common mathematical language "is" and "must be" are the same : "two plus two is four" and "two plus two must be equal to four" does nor mean different facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are unfortunately several ambiguities in the two sentences.
The first one is the precise definition of the word *integer*. In mathematics, an integer is an element of $\Bbb Z$. But in the context of this video, I wonder whether it should not be understood as a *natural number*, that is, an element of $\Bbb N$. On the other hand, the second question refers to negative numbers...
The second ambiguity is indeed the implicit use (or not) of quantifiers.

**First question**. Neither  the sentence "*The sum of two integers is positive*" nor the sentence "*The sum of two natural integers is positive*" is a mathematical statement because it is false for the pair $(0, 0)$ and true otherwise.

**Second question**. The sentence "*The sum of two natural integers can never be negative*" is true (and hence is a mathematical statement), and the sentence "*The sum of two integers can never be negative*" is false (and hence is also a mathematical statement), if you consider there is an implicit universal quantifier: it is not true that the sum of two any integers can never be negative, because, for instance, $(-1) + 0$ is negative.

However, the sentence "*The sum of two natural integers is not negative*" is true (and hence is a mathematical statement) but the sentence "*The sum of two integers is not negative*" can be either true or false (and hence is not a mathematical statement).

In conclusion, I fully subscribe to Daniel W. Farlow's persistent warning: be careful when mixing language with mathematical logic!

Comment: wow, thanks for that technically insightful comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Sum of 2 integers is positive.

This statement is ambiguous. It could be interpreted as

$\exists  x, y \in Z: x+y\gt 0\space\space$  (a true statement)

or as

$\forall  x, y \in Z: x+y\gt 0\space\space$  (a false statement)

> Sum of 2 integers can never be negative.

This statement can only be interpreted as

$\forall  x, y \in Z: x+y\ge 0\space\space$ (a false statement)